# FCM - Messaging: The notification permission was not granted and blocked instead. firebase_messaging/permission-blocked

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I'm using FCM notification on Flutter app. On the web part when I block notifications, I'm encountering this pop-up (`alertDialog`) saying:

`Error![firebase_messaging/permission-blocked] Messaging: The notification permission was not granted and blocked instead.`

How can I prevent this from popping up? I want it to not show up when I block notifications.

I expect it to work like on android, and simply do not display anything if user denied notification permission